# Codeigniter .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello i have a problem with htacces in codeigniter.

First: my link is this `https://www.subdirectory.example.com/test1/test2/`
in config.php set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.subdirectory.example.com/test1/test2/';
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

What settings make's on .htacces and where put this..
in Root or in application folder because the first page i see displayed but when i clicked on a link not working and i have Error internal 500
Example: www.cargus.taune-razvan.ro/test1/test2/

Comment: It seems that your htaccess file code is not correct. 
I want to ask:
why you are adding .htaccess file . (for removing index.php ?)
can you put your htaccess file code here.